# What is the verb meaning of "wind" in "You wound me"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

> "Why, Jaime, my sweet brother," he said,"You **wound** me. You know
>   how much I love my family."

This sentence is extracted from **the Game of Thrones**.
I have looked up the dictionary but still don't understand the verb meaning of "**wind**".
 Whether it means Jamie **misunderstands** Tyrion or Jamie **make Tyrion confused**? I think both of the two understandings state show a meaning of turning or twisting.

Comment: Google "wound". It's the number 1 verb definition.

Comment: [Wound](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wound): Injure (a person’s feelings):

Comment: Perhaps the person speaking was a mechanical robot, and Jaime its brother turned the key in its back to set it going...so that Jaime did wind it up.  But I doubt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, "wound" is not the past tense of wind (as in to "wind up a clock", nor as in "the wind blows"). It is instead the verb form of the noun "wound", meaning an injury of some description.

To wound someone is to cause them a wound (injury). From the Macquarie dictionary—yes, I'm Australian but it's usually closer to "real" English than most US dictionaries :-) :

> ***wound*** /wund/ … *noun* an injury to an organism, usually one involving division of tissue … *verb* to inflict a wound upon.

Also in the context of the quote (assuming you've read the books or seen the TV show), this wound has nothing to do with an actual *physical* injury; it's more of an emotional wound because Jaime Lannister said something hurtful to his brother.